# Aligning legends to the right in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to align legends on my figure to the right. Here is the section of the script that performs the alignment. It works when I save the image as .png or .jpeg, but fails for .pdf and .eps. Any solution/suggestion would be warmly welcomed. Thanks in advance.

```
# Shrink current axis by 20%
box = ax1.get_position()
ax1.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])
    
leg=ax1.legend(loc='center left', fontsize=tsize, ncol=1, frameon=False, fancybox=False, facecolor=None, edgecolor=None, framealpha=None, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
# get the width of your widest label, since every label will need 
# to shift by this amount after we align to the right
renderer = fig.canvas.get_renderer()
shift = max([t.get_window_extent(renderer).width for t in leg.get_texts()])
for t in leg.get_texts():
    t.set_ha('right') # ha is alias for horizontalalignment
    tmp_shift = abs(shift - t.get_window_extent(renderer).width)
    t.set_position((tmp_shift-50,0))
    
fnam = path+'figure.'+fmt
plt.savefig(fnam,format=fmt,dpi=DPI,bbox_inches="tight",pad_inches=0.05)
print('Written file', fnam)
```

Here is a minimal script to produce the plot.

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
rc('text', usetex=True)
# create figure suitable for A4 format
def mm2inch(*tupl):
 inch = 25.4
 if isinstance(tupl[0], tuple):
  return tuple(i/inch for i in tupl[0])
 else:
   return tuple(i/inch for i in tupl)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=mm2inch(200.0, 150.0), dpi=200)

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=1)

for axis in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
  ax1.spines[axis].set_linewidth(1)

ax1.set_ylabel(r"$y$",fontsize=20)
ax1.set_xlabel(r"$x$",fontsize=20)

ax1.axvline(-10,ls='', marker='o', markersize=8, markeredgewidth=2, markeredgecolor='black', markerfacecolor='white', label=r'$\overline{P_{uu}}$')
ax1.axvline(-10,ls='', marker='s', markersize=8, markeredgewidth=2, markeredgecolor='black', markerfacecolor='white', label=r'$-\overline{T_{uu}}$')
ax1.axvline(-10,ls='', marker='^', markersize=8, markeredgewidth=2, markeredgecolor='black', markerfacecolor='white', label=r'$\overline{\Pi_{uu}}$')
ax1.axvline(-10,ls='', marker='d', markersize=8, markeredgewidth=2, markeredgecolor='black', markerfacecolor='white', label=r'$\overline{D_{uu}}$')
ax1.axvline(-10,ls='', marker='x', markersize=8, markeredgewidth=2, markeredgecolor='black', markerfacecolor='white', label=r'$-\overline{\epsilon_{uu}}$')

ax1.set_xlim(0,25)
ax1.set_ylim(-0.25,0.5)
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=10)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=10)
ax1.tick_params(which='both',bottom=True, top=True, left=True, right=True)
ax1.tick_params(which='both',labelbottom=True, labeltop=False, labelleft=True, labelright=False)
ax1.tick_params(which='both', width=1)
ax1.tick_params(which='major',length=15)

#-------------Part of the code which performs shrinking and alignment----------
# Shrink current axis by 20%
box = ax1.get_position()
ax1.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])

leg=ax1.legend(loc='center left', fontsize=17, ncol=1, frameon=False, fancybox=False, facecolor=None, edgecolor=None, framealpha=None, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
renderer = fig.canvas.get_renderer()
shift = max([t.get_window_extent(renderer).width for t in leg.get_texts()])
for t in leg.get_texts():
    t.set_ha('right') # ha is alias for horizontalalignment
    tmp_shift = abs(shift - t.get_window_extent(renderer).width)
    t.set_position((tmp_shift-50,0))
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

fmt='pdf'
fnam = 'figure.'+fmt
plt.savefig(fnam,format=fmt,dpi=200,bbox_inches="tight",pad_inches=0.05)
print('Written file', fnam)
```

It works for png and jpeg, but fails for pdf.

[png image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LUv4.png)
[pdf image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGocO.png)

Comment: can you pare this down to a minimal script that runs?

Comment: @PaulH I edited the question and provided a minimal example to produce the plot. I have also attached two images that explains the problem. Thank you very much for your suggestion.